# FullCalendar Cross Domain Issue

Tags: fullcalendar, cors, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to set up FullCalendar on my localhost to test it out. Here's the code:

```
$( '.calendar' ).fullCalendar( {
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventSources: [
        {
            url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/feed_one",
            className: 'feed_one'
        },
        {
            url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/feed_two",
            className: 'feed_two'
    ]
} )
```

I got this error in my console instead, and the events are not displayed:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/feed_one. 
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. localhost:1

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/feed_two. 
Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. localhost:1
```

From my research it seems like this is a `Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing` issue, but I don't know how to fix it.

Would appreciate it if someone could help me out, or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to make a JSONP request for cross domain access. Could you please set the following properties and check if this works out for you.

You can get the detailed description of JSONP over [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)...

```
eventSources: [
    {
        url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/feed_one",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        className: 'feed_one'
    },
    {
        url: "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/feed_two",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        className: 'feed_two',
]
```

Comment: Thank you. This seemed to solve the error. However, the calendar is still not display any events. Any thought on how I could test to see where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue. It was fixed after adding to code `<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar-1.6.2/fullcalendar/gcal.js'></script>`

Comment: I was missing this file reference, and adding it fixed the problem.

Comment: I found the same error while trying to use such lib. After that I added discribed above and error gone. Also such troubleshooting helped some people too. So not my troubleshooting, but you comment is not related.